# .htaccess rewrite base URL up one directory level

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an established Drupal installation at `example.com/drupal` - and now I need to move the installation up one level to the domain root.

So the rewrite rule I need is to redirect all existing URLs - e.g. `example.com/drupal/some_section/somepage` to `example.com/some_section/somepage` etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule   ^drupal/(.+)$   $1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1. I just unsure if this will be enough -- maybe 301 redirect will be required (instead of just rewrite as Drupal may detect original URL (sorry, I'm not familiar with Drupal at all)) + Drupal config change ... but that is up to OP to figure out.

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right Lazy...  I'll need to test this.  It may not be workable after all.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting URLs like `example.com/drupal/...` will help if people go to `example.com/drupal/...` but it seems you want it the other way: people use `example.com/...` and go to you site.

For that, I think you need to change the DocumentRoot in your web server configuration or setup a virtual host for example.com

Comment: Imagine that the site is already moved. Now I just want the old URLs that are still being used by various sources to redirect to the new locations.

Comment: @Michael For that you definitely want to do 301 Permanent Redirect, especially from SEO point of view.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. You are right, and I've done the 301 Permanent Redirect.  Works good.